# Underscores in variable names and Emacs `f90-mode`

Tags: emacs

Editing Fortran in Emacs with `f90-mode`, I would like the “word commands” `M-b`, `M-f`, `M-d`, `M-DEL` and so on to act on “words” as separated by underscores.  On the other hand, for the syntax highlighting, commands like `C-M-f`, and so on, the underscores obviously must not break apart identifiers.

`subword-mode` partially does this: `M-f` and `M-d` act like I want, but `M-b` and `M-DEL` still treat the *whole* identifier as one word.  To illustrate: if point is after `some_thing`, `M-b` (`subword-backward`) will move it to `s`; after that, `M-f` (`subword-forward`) will move point to `_`.

In `f90-mode`, `_` has syntax class `"w"` (word).  If I change it to `"_"` (symbol) or `"."` (punctuation), I get the desired behavior, but then `some_thing` will also be two words to font lock and completion.  E.g., `program my_prog; end` will be completed only to `end my`, and `write_me` would be incorrectly fontified (`write` as a keyword).

How do I get both things at once?

PS: This is GNU Emacs 24.

---

EDIT: Here is the complete code I ended up using, building on cadrians answer (thanks!)

```
(let ((adv (cons 'advice
                 (lambda ()
                   (let ((os (char-syntax ?_)))
                     (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "_")
                     ad-do-it
                     (modify-syntax-entry ?_ (string os))))))
      (fun '(subword-forward subword-kill subword-backward
             subword-backward-kill subword-downcase subword-upcase
             subword-transpose)))
  (dolist (f fun)
    (ad-add-advice f (list 'underscore-wrap nil t adv)
                   'around 'last)
    (ad-activate f)))
```

I added a `let` so as not to change the syntax permanently, and used `ad-add-advice` to be able to put it in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use defadvice:

```
(defadvice forward-word (around eif-forward-word activate)
  "forward-word, with the underscore not being a letter"
  (interactive "p")
  (modify-syntax-entry ?_  "_")
  ad-do-it
  (modify-syntax-entry ?_  "w"))
```

Modify `forward-word`, `backword-word`, `left-word`, and `right-word`.